# Change the color of EditText when setting value

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have 8 EditText.

User enters some value into some EditText and the blank EditText got filled by some calculation.

I wrote the code to change the color of EditText as below:

```
                   if (ng1 == 0) {
                                if (Goal >= 0 && Goal <=10)
                                    eg1.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
                                 eg1.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

                            }

                            if (ng2 == 0) {
                                if (Goal >= 0 && Goal <=10)
                                    eg2.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
                                eg2.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }

                            if (ng3 == 0 ) {
                                if (Goal >= 0 && Goal <=10)
                                    //eg3.setText("");
                                    eg3.setText(Float.toString(Goal));
                                eg3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }
```

Means ihe scenario is, user can put value in 2 , 3 , 4 what ever he wants and the rest of the edittext will be filled on basis of the some computation and to show the user which got filled i need to change it into blue color , and if the user edit the edittext the color is now coming blue but i want black

Whats the way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use onTouchListner when the user clicks the editText cange the color to Black.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have lots of `EditText` controls which are handled in the same way, I'd suggest using `TextWatcher` ([documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)) to listen to text changes and avoid duplicating the same operations for all 3, 8, or zillion controls.

Please note, that below examples are not compiled and were written in a simple text editor from memory, so changes could be needed to make them compile. However, it's only a template to point you in right direction

First, you create a custom `TextWatcher` implementation in order to have the same `TextWatcher` handle all `EditText`'s

```
private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private EditText mEditText;

    public MyTextWatcher(EditText view) {
        mEditText = view;
    }

    public void afterTextChanged (Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}

    public void onTextChanged (CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //Check if has user focus. if it has, then user is typing smth. set appropriate color
        mEditText.setTextColor(mEditText.hasFocus() ? Color.BLACK : Color.BLUE);
    }
};
```

Then in `onCreate()` you add textChange listeners:

```
eg1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_eg1_id);
eg1.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(eg1));
eg2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_eg2_id);
eg2.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(eg2));
...
egN = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.your_egN_id);
egN.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(eg3));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use text change listener.

```
_edtText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                _edtText.setTextColor(Color.BLACK); // you can set color onTextChanged
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: Although this my work, it is better to provide an brief explanation as to what you changed and what was wrong in OP's code.

Comment: In your code, you are not managing else case that the reason Edittext color always set as Blue.

Comment: I suppose, OP wants to change the color of text to `black` when the user is typing something again in the textbox.

Comment: @PrerakSola YES i want exactly what you said

Comment: yeah so in that case if all conditions got false then it goes in else case where color is black.

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique the scenario is that i have 8 edittext , user can put value in 2 , 3 , 4 what ever he wants and the rest of the edittext will be filled on basis of the some computation and to show the user whch got filled i need to change it into blue color , and if the user edit the edittext the color is now coming blue but i want black

Comment: you mean, when user type in edittext then the color should be black and when text filled by some calculations then the color should be blue?

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique Exactly

Comment: Yes, this would work. I just found this listener... (y)

Comment: @ShoebAhmedSiddique please find the answer below...Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

What i did i just add ontouch listener to all the edit text

```
eg1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg4.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg4.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg5.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg5.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg6.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg6.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg7.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg7.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });

        eg8.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                eg8.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                return false;
            }
        });
```